# Jmeter - Using JSON Extractor for getting variables with the same name

Tags: json, jmeter

This is my JSON:

```
[
{
    "rooms": [
        {
            "name": "Name1",
            "id": 148,
            "isActive": true,
            "properties": {
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Name 2",
            "id": 149,
            "isActive": true,
            "properties": {
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Name 3",
            "id": 150,
            "isActive": true,
            "properties": {
            }
        }
    ],
    "timezone": "America\/New_York",
    "name": "AnotherName",
    "id": 88,
    "isActive": false,
    "properties": {
    }
}]
```

In order to extract the "timezone" field I use: "$..timezone" and in return I get: 
**Result[0]=America/New_York**

Using "$..id" will return:

**Result[0]=88**

**Result[1]=148**

**Result[2]=149**

**Result[3]=150**

The question is: Which syntax to use in order to extract only **Result[0]=88** ?
I've been trying several available options but with no success.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `..` [operator](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators) which means **deep scan** so JMeter finds all `id` attributes and returns all their values.

If you want only the top-level ID for the first entry in the response [JSON Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) you need to explicitly set path to it like:

```
$.[0].id
```

if you need to get the `id` where `timezone` is `America/New_York` - the relevant JSON Path query would be:

```
$..[?(@.timezone == 'America/New_York')].id
```

More information: [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter/)

Comment: Cheers for the detailed info and for the advanced scenarios

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.[*]id` to get **Result[0]=88**

Comment: Worked as a charm. Thanks a lot!